# useEffect EventListener problem REACT HOOKS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-effect, onkeydown

I was trying to make a simple Snake-Game with REACT. Everything was good till I needed to use useEffect to move "snake" when keydown fire.
When I try to put moveSnake() into useEffect it's giving me some error. When I move it and call it outside effect it's making an infinity loop. I'm using functional components. App.js is messed around because I was stressed out because it's not working and tried every single option. Hope you will get everything.

https://github.com/Pijano97/snake-game code is here, thanks.
Also if someone can not access that, here is the code.
The snake component just renders snakeDots with a map.
Food component just creating random food on the map.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Snake from "./Snake";
import Food from "./Food";

function App() {
    const getRandomFoodDot = () => {
        let min = 1;
        let max = 98;

        let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;
        let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;

        return [x, y];
    };

    const [snakeDots, setSnakeDots] = useState([
        [0, 0],
        [2, 0],
    ]);
    const [foodDots, setFoodDots] = useState(getRandomFoodDot());
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState("");

    const moveSnake = () => {
        let dots = [...snakeDots];
        let head = dots[dots.length - 1];

        switch (direction) {
            case "UP":
                head = [head[0], head[1] - 2];
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                head = [head[0], head[1] + 2];
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                head = [head[0] - 2, head[1]];
                break;
            case "RIGHT":
                head = [head[0] + 2, head[1]];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // adding new head
        dots.push(head);
        // removing last dot
        dots.shift();
        setSnakeDots(dots);
    };

    moveSnake();

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 38:
                    setDirection("UP");
                    break;
                case 40:
                    setDirection("DOWN");
                    break;
                case 37:
                    setDirection("LEFT");
                    break;
                case 39:
                    setDirection("RIGHT");
                    break;
                default:
                    setDirection("");
                    break;
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressHandler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPressHandler);
        };
    }, []);

    console.log(direction);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <div className="snake">
                <Snake snakeDots={snakeDots} />
                <Food foodDots={foodDots} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should list your error in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got it correct, but probably you can try this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Snake from "./Snake";
import Food from "./Food";

const getDirection = e => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            return 'UP';
        case 40:
            return 'DOWN';
        case 37:
            return 'LEFT';
        case 39:
            return 'RIGHT';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}

function App() {
    const getRandomFoodDot = () => {
        let min = 1;
        let max = 98;

        let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;
        let y = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) / 2) * 2;

        return [x, y];
    };

    const [snakeDots, setSnakeDots] = useState([
        [0, 0],
        [2, 0],
    ]);
    const [foodDots, setFoodDots] = useState(getRandomFoodDot());
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState({val: ''});

    useEffect(() => {
        let dots = [...snakeDots];
        let head = dots[dots.length - 1];

        switch (direction.val) {
            case "UP":
                head = [head[0], head[1] - 2];
                break;
            case "DOWN":
                head = [head[0], head[1] + 2];
                break;
            case "LEFT":
                head = [head[0] - 2, head[1]];
                break;
            case "RIGHT":
                head = [head[0] + 2, head[1]];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // adding new head
        dots.push(head);
        // removing last dot
        dots.shift();
        setSnakeDots(dots);
    }, [direction]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
            setDirection({ val: getDirection(e) });
        };
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressHandler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPressHandler);
        };
    }, []);

    console.log(direction);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <div className="snake">
                <Snake snakeDots={snakeDots} />
                <Food foodDots={foodDots} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I just created `getDirection` func for getting direction from a key event and added one more `useEffect` with logic from the `moveSnake` function
I didn't know the current functionality of your project, but the code above works, and the shake can be moved.

Comment: That was great, just added interval in first useEffect and condition on useEffect snakeDots.

Comment: Ok, nice. Always happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error which says React limits the amount of re-renders to provent infinate re-renders is because you call moveSnake() inside your App() component, and moveSnake() calls setSnakeDots() which updates the state of snakeDots. When the state of snakeDots gets updated, your App component rerenders, which triggers the calling of moveSnake(), which calls setSnakeDots() which updates the state of your snakeDots which re-renders your App component. Your stuck in an inifinate loop here.

Something that might fix it(although I tested it and the game doesn't proceed past one step) would be setting your moveSnake() function in a timer like

```
function timer(){
    setInterval(function() {
        moveSnake();
        timer()
    }, 1000);
}

timer()
```

Comment: Actually, I had that function, because I need it for "move every 300ms". Have a great day! It was my first post